# How to link MinGW (gcc) and TBB

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, mingw, tbb

I am trying to compile my TBB program using MinGW. I know that TBB is installed on my machine correctly because it compiles just fine in Visual Studio. Do I have to do something more to tell MinGW where TBB is installed? Or is just linking the library all that is needed? I am getting these error, when trying to compile using gcc.

```
 C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\New folder\OpenMP vs TBB>make
g++  -LC:\tbb\tbb\lib\intel64\vc14 -O3 -o pps avl.o main.o parPlaneSweep.o -fopenmp -ltbb
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text+0x433f): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::init()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text+0x435d): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text+0x439d): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::get_initial_auto_partitioner_divisor()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text+0x43d0): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::~task_group_context()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text+0x47d5): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::init()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text+0x47f3): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text+0x4835): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::get_initial_auto_partitioner_divisor()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text+0x4868): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::~task_group_context()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text+0x7743): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_continuation_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text+0x776c): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_child_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text+0x7a66): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::is_group_execution_cancelled() const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text+0x7abc): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_continuation_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text+0x7ae5): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_child_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text+0x8cab): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_continuation_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text+0x8cd4): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_child_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text+0x8f69): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::is_group_execution_cancelled() const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text+0x8fb4): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_continuation_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text+0x8fdd): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_child_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD1Ev[__ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD1Ev]+0x43): undefined reference to `tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_execute(tbb::interface7::internal::delegate_base&) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD1Ev[__ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD1Ev]+0x4e): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::is_group_execution_cancelled() const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD1Ev[__ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD1Ev]+0x73): undefined reference to `tbb::interface5::internal::task_base::destroy(tbb::task&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD1Ev[__ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD1Ev]+0x87): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::~task_group_context()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD1Ev[__ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD1Ev]+0xe3): undefined reference to `tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_terminate()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD1Ev[__ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD1Ev]+0xf1): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::reset()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD1Ev[__ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD1Ev]+0x10b): undefined reference to `tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_initialize()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD1Ev[__ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD1Ev]+0x12e): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::reset()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD0Ev[__ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD0Ev]+0x44): undefined reference to `tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_execute(tbb::interface7::internal::delegate_base&) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD0Ev[__ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD0Ev]+0x4f): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::is_group_execution_cancelled() const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD0Ev[__ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD0Ev]+0x74): undefined reference to `tbb::interface5::internal::task_base::destroy(tbb::task&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD0Ev[__ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD0Ev]+0x88): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::~task_group_context()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD0Ev[__ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD0Ev]+0xf3): undefined reference to `tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_terminate()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD0Ev[__ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD0Ev]+0x101): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::reset()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD0Ev[__ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD0Ev]+0x11b): undefined reference to `tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_initialize()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD0Ev[__ZN3tbb4flow11interface105graphD0Ev]+0x13e): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::reset()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text.unlikely+0xf3): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy::free(tbb::task&) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text.unlikely+0xff): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::~task_group_context()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.text.unlikely+0x118): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy::free(tbb::task&) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: parPlaneSweep.o:parPlaneSweep.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN3tbb10interface98internal9flag_taskE[__ZTVN3tbb10interface98internal9flag_taskE]+0x14): undefined reference to `tbb::task::note_affinity(unsigned short)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'pps' failed
make: *** [pps] Error 1
```

This is what my current Makefile looks like right now.

```
CC=gcc
CPLUSPLUS = g++ 
OPTFLAGS = -O3
TBB_INCLUDE_PATH = C:\tbb-2020.1-win\tbb\include
TBB_LIBRARY_PATH = C:\tbb\tbb\lib\intel64\vc14

all: pps

pps: avl.o main.o parPlaneSweep.o
    $(CPLUSPLUS) -L$(TBB_LIBRARY_PATH) $(OPTFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -fopenmp -ltbb

avl.o: avl.h avl.c
    $(CC) -c $(OPTFLAGS) -fPIC avl.c

main.o: main.cpp parPlaneSweep.h
    $(CPLUSPLUS) -c $(OPTFLAGS) -fopenmp main.cpp 

parPlaneSweep.o: parPlaneSweep.h parPlaneSweep.cpp
    $(CPLUSPLUS) -c $(OPTFLAGS) -ITBB_INCLUDE_PATH -fPIC -fopenmp parPlaneSweep.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o
    rm pps
```

Comment: The `vc14` in `C:\tbb\tbb\lib\intel64\vc14` scares me a little. GCC cannot use Visual Studio libraries. I'm sorry I didn't spot this in your earlier question and save you some time. You will have to download the library for your compiler (and very likely compiler version) or download the source code and build the library for your compiler. I'm afraid I don't know this technology and the download options require registration so I can't even find out for you.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. That does seem to be the issue. I have been looking everywhere for the gcc specific library files, but every version I have seen is still only for VS. Does anyone know where I can find them?

Comment: MSYS2 includes tbb. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2

Answer (score 3):

MinGW and MSVC are different toolchains, even though both can produce EXE/DLL files in "native" Windows format. But the C++ symbol decoration (aka mangling) is done very differently, so the same function in source code would be compiled into differently named binary functions. There might also be more application binary interface (ABI) differences between the toolchains. Therefore you cannot simply link object files/libraries created by/for MinGW and by/for MSVC; you need all libraries to be prepared with the same toolchain.

You can build TBB binaries for MinGW on your own (it's supported in TBB makefiles), or you can try finding a ready-to-use package such as the one for MSYS2 mentioned in the comments to the question.